# What is the wisdom behind the importance of getting married and have children?

Tags: sunni, nikah

What is the wisdom behind the importance of getting married and having children in Islam?

I ask because getting married and having children is a full time commitment, to which you have to dedicate your life to, meaning, you will hardly have time left for much else.

I ask because in this life, there are a trillion and one things a person can do, experience, explore, see etc etc and marriage is 1 of those things and children is another of those things.

Which is why I want to know about the wisdom behind the importance given to marriage and having children, where you normally would have to give up all the other things you could do in your life if you don't get married and have children.

I am only talking about things which are not haraam.   For example:

Learning how to ride a horse
Learning archery
Learning rock climbing
Learning languages
Sky diving
Scuba diving
Learning to fly a helicopter
Going to see all the amazing landscapes of the world
Mountain biking

I mean the list is endless.  If you get married, the average person would end up spending all his money and time on his family.  If he has money, it normally means he works hard to earn the money, so he will lack time.  If he lacks money, it normally means he will have plenty of time, but no money to do and experience the world created by God.

Sunni view preferred.

Comment: please avoid "why" type questions

Comment: If there was no you, then you can't miss-out on flying a helicopter.  But that is not the point of the question.  I just want to know why Islam puts so much emphases on getting married and having children.

Comment: Isn't that the prophet pbuh commanded marriage enough for you to believe in it. check out: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7576/is-marriage-obligatory-in-islam-and-how-did-the-prophet-react-to-people-who-take

Comment: @PersianCat sure it helped me too

Comment: @user3550 I am not a religious person and not pro or against marriage (I am single!) but according to most researches marriage helps **most** people to get ride of stress and find more confidence

Comment: point no 1 . all this can be done even after marriage . point no 2. you can do all these things in 2 to 5 years and get married after that :)

Comment: @Noah, I don't understand your reply.  Your reply seems to imply that God can't keep his creation alive, and that he needs the help of his own creation to keep it alive...

Comment: @user3550— no, that's an imaginary statement. But will delete it.

Answer (score 2):

"Why" questions are not standard questions in all religions, BUT
I'd answer your question with 2 approaches:

1) Why Islam assert marriage? Islam uses marriage as a weapon against many sins and as a tool to gain many profits which takes too much time to even list them here. You can try to read some books about each one of them if you're really curios. I think that's why Islam likes marriage a lot.

2) Why marriage is important philosophically? Do we want children or not? If "not" then human-kind is prone to extinct in no time. But if children are necessary there must be some kind of system to help them grow and become successful in future. Islam thinks that the best system is a natural family made by marriage. Of course some other systems have been tested through history and you can read about the results of their experiments in pages of psychology books if you like.

To wrap everything up, Islam defines marriage as a method for people to keep them safe from sins and to give them some hidden profits (read more about it in Hadith) and to make their children grow in a better social system.

My statement was **trying** to be *rational* other than to struggle to prove itself through Quran or Hadith.