# Is it acceptable for a Muslim boy to never get married, instead travelling the world writing books?

Tags: nikah

I don't want to get married ever. I am a Muslim boy who knows marriage is Sunnah, but I just don't want to spend my life raising kids. I want to travel the world, write books and remain single. I am not the kind of person who wants to get tied down and voluntarily take responsibilities. I want to travel for life. Would that be okay?

Comment: How would you satisfy your sexual desire?

Comment: Hey Ahmed. I think you've never enjoy the presence of a girl or lady beside yourself. Her existence beside you will calm you down and it's separate from sexual aspects. Don't be  dumb about girls...

Comment: You don't have to have kids if you get married!

Comment: See also: "[Is it mandatory to get married in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10693/9123)" and "[What is the wisdom behind the importance of getting married and have children?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7936/9123)"

Comment: Oh, yea, what @azam presented,can be deemed as the related constructive links.

Answer (score -1):

Allah said in Quran (what means):

> > وَمِنْ آيَاتِهِ أَنْ خَلَقَ لَكُم مِّنْ أَنفُسِكُمْ أَزْوَاجًا لِّتَسْكُنُوا إِلَيْهَا وَجَعَلَ بَيْنَكُم مَّوَدَّةً وَرَحْمَةً ۚ إِنَّ فِي ذَٰلِكَ لَآيَاتٍ لِّقَوْمٍ يَتَفَكَّرُون
> >
> > "And among His signs is this, that He created for you wives from among yourselves, that you may find repose in them, and He has put between you affection and mercy. Verily, in that are indeed signs for a people who reflect. (21)"

[Quran, Chapter 30, verse 21]

Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said:

> > النکاح من سنتی فمن رغب عن سنتی فلیس منی
> >
> > Marriage is my sunnah and who ever turns away from my sunnah is not of me
> >
> > Nikaah (Marriage) is Prophet (PBUH)'s permanent sunnah. It is a great sin for a person who can marry but don't marry.

There are more benefits in getting married than being single.

Comment: According this (Arabic) fatwa http://islamqa.info/ar/96977 apparently all ahadith criticizing bachelorhood are weak or baseless! Nevertheless our Messenger (Peace be upon him) was asking us to get married for many good reasons!

Answer (score -1):

This my PERSONAL opinion:
I don't think that it's a must for you to get married. Oh and for all the people who are using this hadith;'Marriage is my sunnah and who ever turns away from my sunnah is not of me' It's about those people who can afford marriage and still don't proceed doing so just because they believe it will reduce their wealth, or putting it simply, it's for those people who don't get married because they don't want to spend any money and all that. Besides, if you can handle yourself independently and don't wish to get married, then there is no need to get married. And anyways, Islam states that nobody (even parents) can not force anyone into marriage, the relationship will only be then officially connubial if both the girl and boy agree to it. But you must keep in mind that if you want to fulfill your sexual desires then you'll have to get married as Islam doesn't allow sexual relationships with anyone except your wife/husband.

Answer (score -1):

Married is a must and obligation, to prevent you make a zinnah. So many hadist, hadisth is exist because to tell you what you should do and don't, if you ignore because your own will and lust, you will get sin.

Answer (score -3):

It's not Okay ! You need to fulfill your sex needs, in Islam the only accepted way to do is to get married. Except if you have no sex needs but in that case you must see a Doctor :)